# Fixing Maximum and Minimum Time for UIDatePicker() in 12 hour Format (AM to PM, PM to AM)Language swift

Tags: swift

Here is my code:

```
let startHour: Int = 23
let endHour: Int = 6
let date1: NSDate = NSDate()
let gregorian: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!
let components: NSDateComponents = gregorian.components(([.day, .month, .year]), from: date1 as Date) as NSDateComponents
components.hour = startHour
components.minute = 0
components.second = 0
let startDate: NSDate = gregorian.date(from: components as DateComponents)! as NSDate
components.hour = endHour
components.minute = 0
components.second = 0
let endDate: NSDate = gregorian.date(from: components as DateComponents)! as NSDate
pickers.datePickerMode = .time
pickers.minimumDate = startDate as Date
pickers.maximumDate = endDate as Date
pickers.setDate(startDate as Date, animated: true)
pickers.reloadInputViews()
```

I am trying to pass input time as `startHour` and `endHour` to `UIDatePicker()` named as `pickers(pickers.minimumDate ,pickers.maximumDate)`. Here it throughs me an output, which just start with 11PM but allowing me to pick 10PM too. And I don't want to pass my input as 23 but as 11 PM , 6 as 6 AM.

Comment: Do not use `NSDate` and `NSCalendar` in Swift. Use `Date` and `Calendar`.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy for ur responds......My code is working Fine without changing NSDate and NSCalender, if I pass startHour as 6 and endHour as 23 its  working, I found in developers docs that maximum date is less than the minimum date both the cases are ignored and it allowes to pick any time.please help me,I want to pass "6 AM" and "11 PM" as inputs...